# Fix div from the bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, fixed

I want to create a section (like the right section on Facebook). A section fixed but from the bottom; as far as I scroll, the section scrolls. But when I reach the bottom of the section, it becomes fixed and stays on screen.

I think it's not possible to do this with pure CSS, maybe JS..

Do you have any solution for making this happen ?

In advance, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using bootstrap will make this easier. You can achieve this by `navbar-fixed-bottom`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="height:1500px">

<nav class="navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <h3>Hello<h3>
  </div>
</nav>
  
<div class="container">
  <h3>Fixed Navbar</h3>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p>A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll.</p>
      <p>A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll.</p>    
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"> 
      <p>A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll.</p>
      <p>A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"> 
      <p>A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll.</p>
      <p>A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll.</p> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<h1>Scroll this page to see the effect</h1>
  
  <div class="col-md-4"> 
      <p>A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll.</p>
      <p>A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll.</p> 
    <div class="col-md-4"> 
      <p>A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll.</p>
      <p>A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll.</p> 
      <div class="col-md-4"> 
      <p>A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll.</p>
      <p>A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll.</p> 

</body>
</html>
```